# is it posible to test if a string includes another string in handlebars?

Tags: handlebars.js

Can I test if a string includes another string in handlebars ? without registering a handlebar helper ?

This would be my code now :

```
 {{#eq message "specialMarker"}}
   <p>some other text</p>
 {{/eq}}
```

I want to return the "some other text" if the `message` string contains the `"special marker"`

Comment: You would need to create a custom helper for that. See: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#custom-helpers

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a helper like this one:

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper("eq", function (options) {
  if (options.fn(this).includes("specialMarker")) {
    return "<p>some other text</p>";
  }
  return "<p>Not included</p>";
});
```

The `hbs` file would be:

```js
{{#eq}}{{message}}{{/eq}}
```

Example in [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/string-includes-hbs-helper-yd937?file=/src/index.js:75-100)